# Index Out of Bound Exception en Java

Tags: java

Me podrian informar que significa esta excepcion de java: Index Out of Bound Exception en Java

Answer (score 2):

Java admite la creación y manipulación de matrices (arrays), como una estructura de datos.

El índice de una matriz es un valor entero que tiene un valor en el intervalo `[0, n-1]`, donde `n` es el tamaño de la matriz. Si se realiza una solicitud de un negativo o un índice mayor o igual al tamaño de la matriz, entonces JAVA arroja una excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

Esto es diferente a C / C ++, donde no se realiza ningún índice de verificación enlazada. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` es una excepción de tiempo de ejecución que se produce solo en tiempo de ejecución.

El compilador de Java no comprueba este error durante la compilación de un programa.